# Chrome extension - onMessage.addListener not picking up message

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension.
I am able to successfully pass messages from my `popup.js` to my `background.js` and then to my `content_script.js`.

In this particular example, however, I am able to get to the function the sends the message from my background script but it is not being "listened" to on my popup.js.

`background.js`

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.log("Connected .....");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log("Value from popup to background :",msg);
        if(msg)
        {
            switch (msg.message)
            {
                case "getKeyList":
                {
                // Does not seem to work

 sendMessageToPopup({"message":"getKeyList"},function(response){;});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function sendMessageToPopup(message, func){
    console.log("Message ",message);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, func);
}
```

`popup.js`

```
function getKeys(){

    sendToBackground(port, {message:'getKeyList'});
    console.log("Values from popup to background:",{message:"getKeyList"});
}
function sendToBackground(port, message)
{
    // This works fine every time
    port.postMessage(message);
}
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    // Does not get called
    console.log("Received at popup ",msg);
}
```

I have verified that the `sendMessageToPopup` function works when called in a different case.

The listener also works when called in a different case.

However, in this particular case, it doesn't work.

Comment: To receive from chrome.runtime.sendMessage you need chrome.runtime.onMessage, but you don't have it. The proper solution here is to use the port.postMessage instead, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Can you please post that as an answer that I can accept?